# Given $\sin(\theta) = \frac14, 0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}2$. Find $\sin(\theta/2)$

Tags: trigonometry

How could I possibly get this equation to end up being one of the answers provided on the sample test?

No matter how I go about it the closest I get is having $\sqrt{15}$ on the numerator but I have no idea how the denominator ends up being $4$...

I assume it was $16$ and I'm supposed to find the square root to simplify it to $4$...

How would I get $16$ though?... The half angle formula states that $1-\cos \theta$ is divided by $2$ and then the square root is found. But no combination of steps is getting me to any of the possible answers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

$$\sqrt{\frac{4-\sqrt{15}}{8}}=\sqrt{\frac{4-\sqrt{15}}{8}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sin\theta=\dfrac{1}{4}\to \cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{15}}{4}$

$$\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{4-\sqrt{15}}{8}}=\sqrt{\frac{2(4-\sqrt{15})}{16}}=\frac{\sqrt{8-2\sqrt{15}}}{4}$$

Answer is (C).

The expression could be simplified further

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4-\sqrt{15}}{2}}=\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}\right)$$

I used a formula to denest the double root
$$\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(a+\sqrt{a^2-b}\right)}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(a-\sqrt{a^2-b}\right)}$$

Hope this is useful

Comment: How did you know to multiply the numerator and denominator by 2?

Comment: @Jason_Silva  Actually I didn't know, indeed my simplification is much better than the multiple choice of the test. At first sight I even didn't see the a,b,c,d results :)  After a second reading I saw that they wanted the result in that awful way and so I multiplied by $2$ because my $4$ had to become an $8$. It's the eye of the expert. I cannot explain it better. BTW I HATE multiple choice test. I never give them to my students. They are free to make always new mistakes...